# Swing Trading Roth IRA & SEC's Reg T+2 amendment?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, regulation, sec

Few resources state that swing trading Roth IRA account would be difficult due to SEC's Reg T+3 which per [SEC Website](https://www.sec.gov/news/press-release/2017-68-0) is now Reg T+2 effective Sept. 5, 2017.

Even prior to SEC's amendment, my thought was if I sell XYZ then immediately buy ABC, as long as my swing exit plan for ABC was 3 or more days later there would be no restriction whatsoever and I could then immediate rebuy XYZ or even ABC, rinse/repeat spacing my repositions 3 days apart.

Is my understanding above correct? Does this avoid "free-riding."

i.e. exit[ABC] --immediate--> entry[XYZ/ABC], as long as I held ABC 3 (now 2) days or more.

Comment: You can swing trade as often as you like as long as you are using settled funds otherwise it is a Free Riding violation.

Comment: In a cash account, you must pay for the purchase of a stock before you can sell it. IOW, the free riding violation occurs when you  sell stock that was purchased with unsettled funds.

Comment: @BobBaerker Reg T+2*3 pertains to Free Riding. I just don't know which part of the transaction triggers the Free Riding. "Using settled funds" does this mean using settled funds to Buy? or the Selling of assets Bought with unsettled funds?

Comment: So effectively with SEC's amendment, swing trading in a Roth IRA (cash account) is plausible as long as each position is held at least 2 days, regardless of time length in-between positions.

Comment: Bear in mind that we're talking about swing trading not day trading.  Otherwise, you run afoul of the Pattern Day Trader rule.

Comment: well if every position is held 2 days, PDT would never apply except at brokers discretion correct?

Comment: By definition, day trading is the  buying and selling of securities  within the same trading day.  The broker has no discretion in this.

Comment: Your Roth IRA _custodian_ might prohibit swing trading with a spacing of three days or so within the IRA account.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Had an experience on the unsettled trades. It was a lesson for me. Otherwise, I'll get a penalty and put my account on hold for 90 days